significance annotations with facet_wrap
I would like to add significance annotations with asterisks between the two bars in each facet of the plot produced by the following dataset and code.
I have tried in vain to reach the desired result using the 'ggpubr' and 'rstatix' libraries. Could you please help me out?
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

overtcovert_longeng <- structure(list(Participant = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S1",
"S2", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S4", "S5",
"S5", "S5", "S5", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S6", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S8", "S8",
"S8", "S8", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S9", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S10", "S11", "S11",
"S11", "S11", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S12", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S13", "S14",
"S14", "S14", "S14", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S16", "S16", "S16", "S16",
"S17", "S17", "S17", "S17", "S18", "S18", "S18", "S18", "S19", "S19", "S19",
"S19", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S20", "S21", "S21", "S21", "S21", "S22", "S22",
"S22", "S22", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S23", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S24", "S25",
"S25", "S25", "S25", "S26", "S26", "S26", "S26"), Condition = structure(c(1L,
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L,
3L, 2L, 4L), levels = c("two trucks will leave today", "we repaired two
trucks", "three will leave\ntoday", "we repaired two" ), class = "factor"),
Judgment = c(2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1,
5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5,
3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5,
5, 5, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5,
4, 4, 5, 5), DP_position = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("subject",
"object"), class = "factor"), DP_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels =
c("overt NP", "covert NP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -104L), class
= c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
  
overtcovert_longeng.plot <- overtcovert_longeng  %>% ggplot(aes(Condition, Judgment, fill = DP_type)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = .5, position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  scale_y_continuous("", expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.1)), limits = c(0, 5)) +
  facet_wrap(~DP_position, scales = "free_x") 

print(overtcovert_longeng.plot)


Two comments: First you should write your example in the body of the question, otherwise the link could be broken and the answer could not be useful anymore for anyone searching for the same issue.
Second: Try using annotate

Does this help? https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif#advanced-example
